# how to see the message that the wp-members account is not confirmed

Tags: wordpress

hello I have a problem with wp-members, in the options I indicated that the user who registers must receive an email to confirm his account, it works perfectly

but when the user tries to connect without having confirmed his account and he enters a good password and a good login, he continues to receive the error message that his login or his password is not valid
when he should receive the message that his account is not active